# Android EditText with multiple Lines automatic line break

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

is it possible to have an EditText with multiple Lines which automatically makes a Line break after every 20th Character the user is typing in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText automatically go to a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123833/edittext-automatically-go-to-a-new-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement TextWatcher interface and implement method afterTextChanged. The method will be invoked after text changed, so you can add the line breaks in it by yourself.

Answer (score 54):

In your XML file create the edittext like this,

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```