# EditText automatically go to a new line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make the `EditText` with max lines of 2 and max length of 20. If the `EditText` length is more than 10, it should automatically go to a new line so the user don't need to press Enter. Can someone help me with this requirement?

Comment: I haven't tried but I think you should try with TextWatcher. When the length reaches 10, add "\n" to the current String.

Answer (score 53):

**ADD this to your EditText xml code**

> android:inputType="textMultiLine"

This will automatically moves your text to next line while entering data.

Comment: this doesn't add \n chars to the string. just breaks the line in the EditText view, which isn't what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 27):

It should exist a most elegant way but this solution might help you as a clue to achieve what you want. First of all, you will need to set your `EditText` values as below:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:maxLength="21"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="2" />
```

**You must to set the `maxLength` attribute to `21`** because the *enter char* (new line) will take one char in the edittext, then the user will only can write `19` chars instead of `20`.
Then, you should use a `TextWatcher` with a `boolean` (used if the user removes his previous chars), and this should be as follows:

```
// init global boolean
private boolean isReached = false;

// in onCreate method
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // if edittext has 10chars & this is not called yet, add new line
        if(textEd.getText().length() == 10 && !isReached) {
            textEd.append("\n");
            isReached = true;
        }
        // if edittext has less than 10chars & boolean has changed, reset
        if(textEd.getText().length() < 10 && isReached) isReached = false;
    }
});
```

***Note:*** However, you should be careful with this code. Indeed, the user can still pressed the `Key Enter` and then, add new lines. Maybe these answers might help you to handle it and keep the user only "on your road": [Prevent enter key on EditText but still show the text as multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070805/prevent-enter-key-on-edittext-but-still-show-the-text-as-multi-line)

Comment: For second and further lines the code will not handle to move for next line. It leads to do mathematical calculations

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the Input Type to `textMultiLine`

```
  <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the EditText to display 2 lines. You can write like  this:

```
android:maxLength="20"
android:maxLines="2"
android:singleLine="false"
android:layout_width="Your Choice"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the lines, do something like:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="2" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="1" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="2" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

you could also play with this parameter (**Does NOT work for Android <= 3.0**):

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

And for the number of characters, do something like:

```
EditText et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20); //Filter to 20 characters
et.setFilters(filters);
```

or, use this other parameter,

`android:maxLength="20"` in the `xml`

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want automaticly enter when edittext length is more than 10, so basicly 10 character per lines and maxline is just 2

Comment: Just FYI **maxLines** attribute (when set > 2 lines) does not work in Android < 3... too! It's still set to 2 lines (whatever the value).

Answer (score 0):

textView.setText("Your text"+"\n"+"Your text");