# Android EditText failed to wrap text for a space followed by a long link

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I found this problem reproducible on many apps e.g. Twitter for Android. If we have this long link `https://example.com/test/path/123456789012345678901234567890`, when we pasting it into an EditText, it will look like this:

[image: Link without space prefix]

But if we insert a space before this link, line wrap for EditText will refuse to work like this:

[image: Link with space prefix]

Sometime it also happens on TextView but can be fixed by setting `MovementMethod` to `BaseMovementMethod`.

Are there any option for EditText or workaround to this?

Comment: Found a possible related method StaticLayout.generate()

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

or check this solution of Fllo [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123833/edittext-automatically-go-to-a-new-line/23125675#23125675)