# Delete Character & Character length limit not working in MultiLine EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, android-textwatcher

I am using multi line edit-text, I restrict character not exceed 42 in Text Watcher but I cant able to delete char in my edit-text it moves to new line.How to delete characters and add new line if character in line exceeds the limit?

**XML Code :**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Thank you visit again"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:lines="3"
            android:ems="18"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**Java Code:**

```
footerEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if (count % 42 == 0)
                {
                    ((Editable) s).append("\n");
                    footerEdt.setSelection(footerEdt.getText().length());
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123833/edittext-automatically-go-to-a-new-line

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
footerEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if (count % 42 == 0)
            {
                ((Editable) s).append("\n");
                footerEdt.setText(s);
                footerEdt.setSelection(footerEdt.getText().length());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Will not it create infinite loop?